# pong game two players tkinter error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

i tried to execute this code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import functools
import math
import random
import time

class Pong(tk.Canvas):

    DEFAULTS = dict(width=640, height=480,background='black',highlightthickness=0)

    def main(cls):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title('Pong')
        root.resizable(False, False)
        root.bind_all('<Escape>', lambda event: root.destroy())
        game = cls(tkFont.Font(family='Book Antiqua', size=15, weight='bold'), 5, 100,background='black', width=640, height=480)
        game.grid()
        root.mainloop()
```

but i had those errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 413, in <module>
    pong.main()
  , line 17, in main
    game = cls(tkFont.Font(family='Book Antiqua', size=15, weight='bold'), 5, 100,background='black', width=640, height=480)
AttributeError: Pong instance has no __call__ method
```

Comment: What is cls that you're passing?

Comment: Can you show us line 413 where you call `pong.main()` and a bit before where you are assigning `pong`?

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
    pong = Pong()
    Pong.main()

Comment: line 413, in <module>
    Pong.main()
TypeError: unbound method main() must be called with Pong instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Answer (score 1):

I can see one main problem so far

cls coming in as a variable

```
def main(cls):
```

Then you are using it like a function

```
game = cls(tkFont.Font(family='Book Antiqua', size=15, weight='bold'), 5, 100,background='black', width=640, height=480)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, this is how you are creating `pong` and calling `main`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pong = Pong()
    pong.main()
```

At the time where you call `Pong()` you are creating an *instance*. As such the `main` method you are calling is an *instance method* where the first implicit parameter is the instance itself. Usually this parameter is named `self` for instance methods—not `cls` as you did.

So if we rename it, it’s clear what’s failing afterwards:

```
game = self(tkFont.Font(…), 5, 100, background='black', width=640, height=480)
```

Keep in mind that `self` is an object, and instance of `Pong`. So it’s not a function and not a constructor you can call; you are actually trying to call the instance which won’t work here.

I think what you actually want to do instead is have the `main` as a “static” method, being the entry point to your application. In that case, you should add the `@classmethod` decorator in front of the method declaration:

```
@classmethod
def main(cls):
    root = tk.Tk()
    # …
```

In that case, `cls` will be indeed the type `Pong`, which you can call later to create a `Pong` object.

You should change your `__name__ == '__main__` part to just `Pong.main()` though, as you are no longer calling `main` for an *instance* but the whole type.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pong.main()
```

Comment: i have done what you mean and i had error: Pong.main()
TypeError: unbound method main() must be called with Pong instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: @user3200290 Then you seem to have forgotten to add the `@classmethod` line in front of the `def main`.

Comment: i'm sorry, that was because i forgot to put the decorator but now i had this error: Pong.main()
AttributeError: class Pong has no attribute 'main'

Comment: Uhm, make sure your indentation is still correct, so that the function is still part of the `Pong` class.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a very strange thing -- you are creating a subclass of tk.Canvas, yet you don't initialize tk until after you create this object. That's not the right way to be using tkinter. You should initialize Tk outside of the scope of this class, or don't inherit from tk.Canvas.

I recommend you restructure your code so that you initialize tkinter first, and *then* create the instance of your game.

For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Pong(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, root)
        <put other "main" code here if you want>

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    pong = Pong(root)
    pong.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```